# Getting an Trueerror message

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the error "TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list." Not sure what to do about it. Thanks for the help!

```
if iput == 1:
    numresistors = [input("Number of resistors?")]
    if numresistors == [2]:
        r1 = raw_input("Enter first resistor:")
        r2 = raw_input("Enter second resistor:")
        R1 = Parsing(r1)
        R2 = Parsing(r2)
        req = R1.valueParsing() + R2.valueParsing()
        req2 = fmtnum(req)
        print "The value of the series resistors is %s." % req2

    else:
        sumr = 0
        for x in range (numresistors):
            sumr = sumr + x
        print "The value of the series resistors is %s." % sumr
```

Answer (score 1):

`numresistors` is being stored as a list containing a single value

```
 numresistors = [input("Number of resistors?")]
```

The error you are getting is saying that the `range` function doesn't know what to do with a list. You could either call `range` with the only item in the list (`range(numresistors[0])`) or not store it as a list in the first place.

```
numresistors = input("Number of resistors?")
```